# how to download blob based file from MySQL database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, download, blob

How can i make a PHP script that will allow me to download a file from a database in MySQL.
I have the following table named `files` where the uploaded file is saved in a `BLOB` based field.

```
+-------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+
|fileID | fileName | fileType | fileSize   |fileData           | userID |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+
| 1     | file1    | JPEG     | 211258     |[BLOB - 206.3 KiB] | 1      |
| 2     | file2    | PNG      | 211258     |[BLOB - 201.3 KiB] | 1      |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+
```

I cannot figure out a way to call the file to download and every time i try, i get the binary data of the file, such as random numbers and symbols.

I have tried this query where parameters are passed through (fileID, fileName, fileType) to a download.php page:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['fileID']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['fileName']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['fileType']);

$SELECT = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE fileID = $id AND fileName = $name ";
$result = mysqli_query($SELECT, $link);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

header("Content-type: $type");  
echo $result['fileData'];
```

But this leads to a blank page with no output.

How can I download, for example, file1 as a JPEG file to my hard drive?

Comment: a good reason not to store files in the db.

Comment: @Dagon Where should i store them then?

Comment: `Content-type` should be `image/jpeg` that may or may not fix the issue you are having.  Honestly you should have just stored paths of the images in the database instead of storing them as blobs

Comment: files should be stored in the files system

Comment: @elitechief21 the image example i used in the question above is just an example. i want to allow zip folders and word documents to be stored as well.

Comment: You could just use `application/octet-stream` as the `Content-type` but this way is bad to use because the you don't know what type the file is that you are downloading.  You could just store the file type as `image/jpeg`, `image/png`, `application/zip`, etc and keep your code unchanged.

Comment: @Dagon unless you can offer more than an assertion of belief, using examples/data to back your claims, your comments are meaningless

Answer (score 12):

This is the most common problem faced while dealing with the blob file. From your example, I can see that you are saving "fileType" as the extensions of the files (i.e 'jpg' for images, 'pdf' for pdf files etc.), you are uploading.  But instead of that you can can save file type as the MIME content type.

Suppose if you upload a jpeg image - the MIME type will be stored in the "fileType" as the "image/jpeg". Similarly for pdf it will be stored as "application/pdf".  I designed code like  this to download the blob file from the database.  I am going to assume that the files are already uploaded into the database table you created.

**Database table "uploads"**

| fileID | fileName | fileType | fileSize   |fileData  | userID |

**download.php**

```
<?php
$connection =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root"," ",your_database);

$id = 1;

$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE userID = ?";
$result = $connection->execute_query($query, [$id]); 
list($id, $file, $type, $size, $content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $content;
```

You can find the complete code of blob-upload [here](https://github.com/iamSampath/blob-upload).

Comment: this worked fine, when i directed it from HTML to PHP and it forced a download, but with jQuery & PHP it does not work.The content gets echoed in the console, but no file is downloaded!

Comment: @tmzafar yep, that's how AJAX works - the response goes back to the JavaScript. Don't expect to download files via Ajax.

Answer (score -1):

you can use session and post filename and file content to download page

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['filename'] = $filename
$_SESSION['file'] = $file
<a href="download.php">echo "Download File"</a>
```

and in download.php use this code

```
session_start();
$filename = $_SESSION['filename'];
$file = $_SESSION['file'];
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $file;
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with session variables but with mime type