# PHP LongBlob Upload/Download not working with pictures

Tags: php, file, png, blob, gif

I have to store lots of documents in my database and i manage to make it work with PDF.
When i try to upload JPG or GIF for example, the content didn't show when i re-download it from the download function below.

Download function :

```
    public function downloadFile($id) {
    if($id!=null){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM document WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
      header("Content-length:".$row['taillefichier']);
      header("Content-type:" . $row['typefichier']);
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['nomfichier']);
      echo $row['fichier'];
    }
  }
```

Comment: *"When i try to upload JPG or GIF for example, the content didn't show when i re-download it."* - Question is; is there any content that was uploaded to db to start with? Are you also checking for errors?

Comment: ...and if there is content sent to db, what is the size as compared to the file's source?

Comment: Yes, i can download it from MySQL Blob field, but my PHP download function doesn't seems to work, it always show me content error when trying to opening it after using to download function, The size is 209942 in the size field of MySQL table and 205000 in the blob field

Comment: see if there's anything coming from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and from the other comment I left above

Comment: I have edit my comment answer ! error reporting doesn't seems to show me something in particular

Comment: Seeing the size differences, it seems that something got cut off somewhere and/or interrupted. Make sure there isn't an upload size restriction somewhere, such as during the upload process, and/or in the HTML form itself. TBH, I don't know what else it could be. And this condition `if($id!=null)` is unknown, since you seem to be querying elsewhere, so that could be related.

Comment: The condition comes from the paramter of the function ( which i forgot to put with) but i don't know why a PDF file works and not a picture ? Maybe there is extra header to put ?

Comment: Come to think of it, yes. `header('Content-type:image/png');` for PNG - `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` for JPG and `header("Content-type: image/gif");` for GIF, try those. That escaped me completely; lack of coffee *lol*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145978/discussion-between-kryze-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i find the answer to my own question and i'll post the updated function here

```
    public function downloadFile($id) {
    if($id!=null){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM document WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
      header("Content-length:".$row['taillefichier']);
      header("Content-type:".$row['typefichier']);
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['nomfichier']);
      header("Content-type:".$row['typefichier']);
      ob_clean();
      flush();
      echo $row['fichier'];
    }
  }
}
```

See more here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318718/7295677