# How is the output of a php script made to be the resource of the URL that contains the script

Tags: php, url

I want to create a url for an image retrieved from my database using, for example, `http://example.com/getimage.php?id=20` . It will assign the url to an image for the CloudConvert image processing API. After getimage.php has retrieved the image from the database how does that retrieved image, now in a variable in the script, become the resource pointed to by the URL? Do I need to put an echo statement or a return statement in getimage.php or is something else needed?

Comment: According to the documentation, you need to first create a process then using the process ID initiate a conversion. https://cloudconvert.com/api/v1/conversions#create

Comment: I have a CloudConvert process. From CloudConvert's example in the link you supplied ehe second key/value pair in a process is ```"file" => "http://url/to/my/file.ext",``` . This will assign the resource value of the URL to _file._ In the example there is a 'normal' URL which will identify, or point to, a resource. My URL is realy a search query in which the script in the query will retrieve an image into a php variable. It won't be an image in a file pointed to by a 'normal' URL. So how do I make the image in the php variable 'look like' a file resource to CloudConvert?

Comment: So in your PHP script make it print the URL and inject that URL into your API call. Does that make sense? Either that, or make your php script render the contents of the image file itself.

Comment: This example might help you understand the basic process. It will need slight modification obviously (to run the correct SQL for your database, and to set the correct content-type and so on), but hopefully you get the general idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318718/5947043

Answer (score 0):

You need to first output the appropriate header, then output the binary data:

```php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $imageContent;
```