# How to display pdf file as downloadable from BLOB type from mysql in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading pdf file as BLOB type in mysql. Now I want to download that file using hyperlink tag. How to do that?. The below code is not working.
Upload code

```
function do_upload_result($img){
 $files = $_FILES[$img];
  $ci = & get_instance();
  $ci->load->library('upload');
  $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
  $_FILES[$img]['name'] = time().'_'.$files['name'];
  $filename=$_FILES[$img]['name'];
  $_FILES[$img]['type'] = $files['type'];
  $_FILES[$img]['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'];
  $_FILES[$img]['error'] = $files['error'];
  $_FILES[$img]['size'] = $files['size'];
  $ci->upload->initialize($config);
  if ($ci->upload->do_upload($img))
  {
    $prod_img = array('upload_data' => $ci->upload->data());
  }
  else
  {
  }
  return $ci->upload->data();


 $prod_img = 'marksheet';
$prodimg= do_upload_result($prod_img);
$imgdata = file_get_contents($prodimg['full_path']);

<a href="<?php echo 'data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($value['marksheet']); ?>" target="__blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens instead?

Comment: When i am using the above anchor tag to download the pdf, its showing a blank screen.

Comment: Have you tried checking the markup? Is it generated as expected? Does it work when using **static** markup? If yes, what's the difference? If no, this is neither a PHP nor a CodeIgniter problem

Comment: Can you please how to check using sttaic mark up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to download blob based file from MySQL database in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291361/how-to-download-blob-based-file-from-mysql-database-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've a controller called `Test` and it has method called `download()`. So then the url would be as the following as you tagged the question with CodeIgniter:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/test/download">Download PDF</a>
```

Next up, pull off `BLOB` data for the file from the database and put it inside the method. Assuming you are getting `$value['marksheet'];` from your database.

```
<?php

function download() {

    // Prevents out-of-memory issue
    if (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    // Here you should prepare $value['marksheet'];

    // Notice I passed $value['marksheet'] in base64_encode
    $encoded_data = base64_encode($value['marksheet']);

    // Decodes the encoded data
    $decoded_data = base64_decode($encoded_data);

    // Set a path where file_put_contents() will create a file
    $file = APPPATH . '../upload/temporary_file.pdf';

    // Writes data to the specified file
    file_put_contents($file, $decoded_data);

    // Modify the name as you want
    $filename = 'download_name.pdf';

    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    readfile($file);

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);  
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am not saving any filename like 'your-file.pdf'. I am uploading and converting directly the pdf file into BLOB in mysql table column 'file'. Then how can I get $file?

Comment: You do not need to save 'your-file.pdf'. You misunderstood that. However how did you manage `$value['marksheet'];`. You just need to get the data from the **file** database column and pass to the  `base64_encode()`. I thought `$value['marksheet'];` is the **file** column value. So I passed it to the `base64_encode($value['marksheet'])`. Let me know if you understand.